# VBS drop down list - options pulled from sql server

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm struggling to fix this VBScript to allow me to use the data from my drop down list as a variable for my SQL query.

This is my default.asp page. Here the user selects the customer and dates that they want to query. My VBS was originally designed to select the customer name, submission number, and city from the database. Now all I care about is the customerName column:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
        $( "#datepickstart" ).datepicker();
    });
    </script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
        $( "#datepickend" ).datepicker();
    });
    </script>

    <script>
        $(function(){
        $("#header").load("/../header.htm");
    });
    </script>
    <script language="JavaScript">
    function selSummary_OnChange(stype,customer) {
        document.frmSummary.customer.Value = customer;
        document.frmSummary.Summary.Value = stype;
        document.frmSummary.action = "default.asp";
        document.frmSummary.submit();
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="header"></div>

<form action="billing.asp" id="billing" method="post" target="_blank">
    <table>
        <tr><th colspan=4><b>TESTING!</b></th></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Customer:</td>
            <td><select name="customer">
                <% if Request.Form("customer") = "0,0,0" then %>
                    <option value="0" selected>All
                <% else %>
                    <option value="0">All
                <% end if %>
                <%
                        dim DBCONN
                set DBCONN = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
                DBCONN.CommandTimeout = 60000
                DBCONN.ConnectionTimeout = 60000
                DBCONN.Open "DSN=***;UID=***;PWD=***"
                set DBConnection = DBCONN
                strSQL = "select customerName from log.dbo.customer order by customerName"
                'set DBConnection = GetDataConnection 
                set DBQuery = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
                DBQuery.ActiveConnection = DBConnection
                DBQuery.CommandType = 1
                DBQuery.CommandText = strSQL
                set dbCS = DBQuery.Execute

                dbCS.MoveFirst  
                while not dbCS.EOF
                    strcustomerIdentifier = dbCS.Fields("customerNo").Value & "," & dbCS.Fields("SubNo").Value & "," & dbCS.Fields("city")
                    Response.Write("<option value='" & strcustomerIdentifier & "'")
                    if Request.Form("customer") = strcustomerIdentifier then
                        Response.Write("selected")
                    end if
                    Response.Write(">" & dbCS.Fields("customerName").Value & chr(13))
                    dbCS.MoveNext
                wend
                Set dbCS = Nothing
                %>
                </select></td>
            <td>Start Date: <input type="text" name="datepickstart" id="datepickstart"></td>
            <td>End Date: <input type="text" name="datepickend" id="datepickend"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" id="billingsubmit"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

From there we go to billing.asp. This page should spit out an HTML table based on the user's previous input. I want to be able to use the selection from the customer table as a variable in my SQL string but I am unsure about how to get that accomplished correctly as my attempts have not been working.

I know that "All" won't be a successful variable in my SQL query, so I'm trying to call to 2 different queries. The only difference between them is the addition of (and '" + customer + "') to specify a single customer.

billing.asp

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<html>
<head><title></title>
</head>
<body>
<%
dim startdate
    startdate = request.form("datepickstart")
dim enddate
    enddate = request.form("datepickend")
dim customer
    customer = request.form("customer")
%>

<%
    dim dbconn
    set dbconn = server.createobject("adodb.connection")
    DBCONN.CommandTimeout = 60000
    DBCONN.ConnectionTimeout = 60000
    dbconn.open "dsn=***;uid=***;pwd=***"

    dim billingtrans
    dim sqlstr
if request.form("customer")="All"
then
    sqlstr = "SELECT sq.*, sq.Total - sq.[Update] as Inquiry from ( select f.customerName, t.[city], sum (t.TransactionCount) as Total, sum (case when  ([format] in (23,25,38) or [format] between 400 and 499 or [format] between 800 and 899) then t.TransactionCount else 0 end) as [Update] FROM [log].[dbo].[TransactionSummary] t INNER JOIN [log].[dbo].[customer] f on t.customerNo = f.customerNo and t.city = f.city and t.subno = f.subno where t.transactiondate between '" + startdate + "' and '" + enddate + "' group by f.customerName,t.city ) sq"
else
    sqlstr = "SELECT sq.*, sq.Total - sq.[Update] as Inquiry from ( select f.customerName, t.[city], sum (t.TransactionCount) as Total, sum (case when  ([format] in (23,25,38) or [format] between 400 and 499 or [format] between 800 and 899) then t.TransactionCount else 0 end) as [Update] FROM [log].[dbo].[TransactionSummary] t INNER JOIN [log].[dbo].[customer] f on t.customerNo = f.customerNo and t.city = f.city and t.subno = f.subno where t.transactiondate between '" + startdate + "' and '" + enddate + "' and '" + customer + "' group by f.customerName,t.city ) sq"
set billingtrans = server.createobject("adodb.recordset")
billingtrans.open sqlstr, dbconn
%>

<table id="billing">
        <tr>
            <td>Customer</td>
            <td>City</td>
            <td>Update</td>
            <td>Inquiry</td>
            <td>Total</td>
        </tr>
<% while not billingtrans.eof %>
        <tr>
            <td><% =billingtrans("customerName") %></td>
            <td><% =billingtrans("city") %></td>
            <td><% =billingtrans("Update") %></td>
            <td><% =billingtrans("Inquiry") %></td>
            <td><% =billingtrans("Total") %></td>
        </tr>
<% billingtrans.movenext
    wend
    billingtrans.close
    dbconn.close
%>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help on this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Move your "All" options outside your loop.

```
              <select Name="customersel" id="customersel">
                <% if Request.Form("customersel") = "0" then %>
                <option value="0" selected>All
                <% else %>
                <option value="0">All
                <% end if 
                do until customersel.EOF%>
                <option value="<%= customersel("customername") %>"><%= customersel("customername") %></option>

                <%
                customersel.MoveNext
                Loop %>
              </select>
```

NB `do until...loop` is an alternative to `while not...wend`. Both are valid, it's just a matter of preference.

You don't actually need the conditional statement to add the `selected` property. As your "All" option is the first in the list, it will be displayed as long as none of the other options are selected.